# The name 'colType' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, string, datareader

I am attempting to loop through a dataset's rows and columns in search for a match between the dataset's `name` column -- and the `ColumnName` from a `DataReader` object.

I have a new table called `RECORDS` which is empty at program startup. I also have a pre-populated table called `ColumnPositions` with a sub-set of column names found in the `RECORDS` table. This routine is intended to show a subset of all the available columns -- as a default display style.

My code works...except for the line of code that gets the `dr["type"]` value.  I get the error:

> The name '`colType`' does not exist in the current context.

As you can clearly see, my string variables are declared outside the WHILE and FOREACH loops.  The line statement `colName =` works just fine. But `colType` fails everytime.  If I do a statement check in the Intermediate Window in VS2010 for `? dr["type"]"` I get the result `integer`.  But when I check `? colType`, I get the above noted error message.

The intellisense for the DataRow object `dr` reveals an array of 6 items.  Index 1 in the array maps to `name`.  Index 2 maps to `type`.  When I check the value of `? dr[2]` in the Intermediate Window, the same result comes back `integer`.  This is correct.  But whenever this value is assigned to `colType`, VS2010 complains.

I'm no newbie to C# so I did a lot of testing and Googling before posting here.  I'm hoping that this is a matter of me not seeing the forest through the trees.

Here's my code:

```
// get table information for RECORDS
SQLiteCommand tableInfo = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA table_info(Records)", m_cnCaseFile);
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(tableInfo);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM ColumnPositions WHERE ColumnStyle_ID = " + styleID + " ORDER BY ColumnPosition_ID ASC", m_cnCaseFile);
SQLiteDataReader colReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

string colName = "";
string colType = "";

if (dt != null && colReader.HasRows)
{
    while (colReader.Read())
    {
        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            colType = Convert.ToString(dr["type"]);
            colName = dr["name"].ToString();

            if (colReader["ColumnName"].ToString() == colName)
            {                                        
                DataGridViewColumn dgvCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
            }

        }
    }
}

dt.Dispose();
colReader.Close();
```

Comment: I should also describe briefly the purpose of the routine.  I have a new table called RECORDS which is empty at program startup.  I also have a pre-populated table called ColumnPositions with a sub-set of column names found in the RECORDS table.  This routine is intended to show a subset of all the available columns -- as a default display style.  The real coding will be inserted in the line of code that defines a new DataGridViewColumn().  But for now, this function illustrates the task quite effectively.

Comment: This is a runtime error that you're getting?  Not a compiler error?

Comment: Yes.  This is a run-time error.

Comment: That's very odd.  Do you by any chance have anything else, like a database column name, that is called `colType`?  Are you doing anything that generates code on the fly?  Is all of this code in the same assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "dr["name"].ToString();", it is better to use "Convert.ToString(dr["name"]);"

Comment: if this answer is helpful, please vote. It is give motivation to answer:).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the string conversion. I tend to use the Convert.ToString() option but wanted to illustrate that both were implemented.  The .ToString() works for the colName.  The .ToString() and the Convert.ToString() for colType fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the array position instead of the column name:

`colType = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);`

and

`colName = dr[0].ToString();`

You probably don't need this, but here is the documentation for values returned by the SQLite PRAGMA table_info() command. [LINK](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)

Comment: I tried this and the same error occurs only for "colType".  I will look at your link in the meantime, thanks.

Comment: Very odd indeed. Try making `colType` an anonymous variable (`var`) instead of a `string`. Maybe the `PRAGMA` statement is returning that column as something other than a `string`.